# Create a paragraph in javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I use the following code in javascript to replace a table content on a click button, but I want to add another paragraph and between them an image.

```
function changeContent() {
    var x = document.getElementById('Table').rows;
    var y = x[0].cells;
    y[0].innerHTML = "some text";
```

Comment: Is it an exercise?

Comment: Show us what you tried already and explain what didn't work about it.

Comment: Would y[0].innerHTML="<p>some text</p><img src="logo_w3s.gif"><p>some other text</p>" work?

Answer (score 4):

You can also create the element, then append as a child to a parent.

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = 'some text here';

document.getElementById('some-parent').appendChild(p);
```